# Spring Boot Actuator Trace HTTP POST request parameters is coming empty

Tags: spring-boot, logging, spring-boot-actuator

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.13 so using Actuator 1.5.13 . When i call with the post request ,request parameters is coming empty.
No other configuration or createing my Actuator repository.
I just using simple actuator trace end point.

Here is my properties:

```
endpoints.trace.enabled=true

endpoints.trace.sensitive=false

management.trace.include=request-headers,response-headers,cookies,errors,parameters
```

Here is the dependency :

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.13.RELEASE</version>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Trace result :

parameters  {}

Request Example :

```
{ 
     "id": 22,            
     "secondid":350052 ,                            
     "flag":0
}
```

Do you have any idea why it is happening and how i can fix it?

Comment: What sort of request are you POSTing?

Comment: I edited and added the request example.Just simple JSON request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters that are traced are those that are available from `javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getParameterMap()`. From its javadoc:

> Request parameters are extra information sent with the request. For HTTP servlets, parameters are contained in the query string or posted form data.

Your HTTP request doesn't have a query string and it isn't POSTing form data so there are no parameters to trace.

Comment: Firstly,Thanks for your help.As I understood,you are saying that no way to get the parameters automaticely with the default actuator trace repo.I have to write my own Trace repository.And if you have time,one more question : If i have to get the parameters on my own repo,what is the benefit of default trace repository.I already can get the request parameters without trace repository.I just asking to learn something about spring boot.Thanks again.Regards.

Answer (score -2):

For example if request is like */api/persons?name=peter*, parameters will be available in the trace.

```
"parameters": {
            "name": [
                "peter"
            ]
        }
```